# Spring 3.2.9 : support for ordered autowired collections

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

Spring 4 provides support for ordered autowired collection. I think 3.2.9 does not, even if it has all the annotations for this.

Could someone confirm this assumption ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like 3.2.9 does not handle @Order for @Autowired collections but il is quite simple to implement this feature via a @PostConstruct (or InitializingBean#afterPropertiesSet()) method :

```
Collections.sort(myCollection, AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.INSTANCE);
```